# How to get video thumbnail along with uri from gallery in android

Tags: java, android

```
@ Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (data.getData()!=null) {
        videoUri = data.getData();


        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO) {
                Toast.makeText(this, data.getData().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else if (requestCode == VIDEO_RECORD_REQUEST) {
                videoUri = data.getData();
                Toast.makeText(this, data.getData().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

I have tried this code it works fine but I also want to get the thumbnail of result video URI.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Video Thumbnail from Uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109057/get-video-thumbnail-from-uri)

Answer (score 0):

in `onActivityResult`

```
String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
cursor.close();

Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(picturePath, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
```

check de this official docs

[developer.android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails)

Comment: you can use a function like this:
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
  ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
  String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
  return Uri.parse(path);
}

Comment: I don't try with the following lines, but may be it works for you, :
String FILENAME = "image.png";
String PATH = "/mnt/sdcard/"+ FILENAME;
File f = new File(PATH);
Uri yourUri = Uri.fromFile(f);